Touchpad Not Working in Kubuntu 20.04 with Kernel 5.15.0-117-generic
I'm experiencing issues with my touchpad not working in Kubuntu 20.04. I have dual-booted with Arch Linux, and the touchpad works fine there, but it is not detected in Kubuntu. Here are the details of my setup:
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-117-generic
Packages Installed:
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
xserver-xorg-input-libinput

When I run xinput list, the touchpad is not listed. I have tried using both Synaptics and Libinput drivers, but nothing has worked so far.
I suspect that the issue might be related to the kernel version, as I've read that downgrading to an older kernel resolved similar issues for others. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with this or if there's another solution I haven't tried.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
